httpPost in Microsoft Teams MessageCard (created via connector) doesn't work
I'm updating an old android app that posts a URL to a teams channel. The MessageCard contains a button with a url, however when clicked nothing happens.
I can curl the url on my laptop without any issues, the resource is on our local network.
Here is the payload I'm sending to the connector:
{
   "@context":"https:\/\/schema.org\/extensions",
   "@type":"MessageCard",
   "themeColor":"F8BA00",
   "title":"Ring! Someone is at the door",
   "text":"Click **Open Door** to open the door",
   "potentialAction":[
      {
         "@type":"HttpPOST",
         "name":"Open Door",
         "targets":[
            {
               "uri":"http:\/\/172.16.2.48:9999\/?open"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}


What might the issue be?
I've no problem connecting to the server myself, the server can talk to teams and generate MessageCards as it should, but for some reason the button doesn't work.

Microsoft Teams might require URLs to use HTTPS instead of HTTP for security reasons. If possible, try to switch to HTTPS to see if it resolves the issue. Could you please check this document and let us know if you have adhered to all the security requirements stated here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/security-requirements

FYI, the target URL must be accessible from the internet, you cannot use localhost.

@Prasad-MSFT I'll look into that, thanks.

@Prasad-MSFT the server is running on an android phone, and the button is accessed from teams on macbooks/pc's. This connector worked previously, it's only when I updated the connector after receiving a warning about deprecation of the old connector that it stopped working.
